# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' why?

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework

I have code

```
 foreach (XElement t in selxml.Elements("Type"))
                printxml.Add(new XElement("Type",
                    new XAttribute("TypeID", t.Attribute("ID").Value),
                    new XAttribute("TypeName", (from pt in fdb.PrintTypes where pt.PrintTypeID == Int32.Parse(t.Attribute("ID").Value) select pt.Name).SingleOrDefault()),
                    new XAttribute("Value", t.Attribute("Value").Value),
                    new XAttribute("ValueName", (from pti in fdb.PrintTypeItems
                                                 where pti.Value == Int32.Parse(t.Attribute("Value").Value) &&
                                                       pti.PrintTypeID == Int32.Parse(t.Attribute("ID").Value)
                                                 select pti.Name).SingleOrDefault())));
```

and VS say

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

why LINQ to Entities? this is Linq to XML. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Yeah but you have a L2E nested query and it doesn't support `Int32.Parse`

Comment: @James hhow to make possible use L2XML nested L2E?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you use the Int32.Parse method before you call the Add method, within the foreach loop. You can save the two as local variables (Value and ID) and use them in your same query.

Comment: +1 good spot actually, I didn't notice that the OP was referencing the `foreach` variable (was too busy looking at the LINQ stuff!).